# on-premise bridge to kubernetes

Tags: visual-studio, kubernetes

Microsoft recently announced the GA for "Bridge to Kubernetes" which enables hybrid development on a kubernetes cluster. Does it also support on-premise kubernetes cluster (without an Internet connection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/bridge-to-kubernetes-ga/#support-for-any-kubernetes):

> Bridge to Kubernetes is expanding support to **any Kubernetes.  Whether
> you’re connecting to your development cluster running in the cloud, or
> to your local Kubernetes cluster**, Bridge to Kubernetes is available
> for your end-to-end debugging scenarios.
>
> Support for Bridge to Kubernetes on any Kubernetes cluster is
> initially available in the VS Code experience and soon after in Visual
> Studio.

So yes, you can use it also with your local kubernetes environment.

More on its [usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/bridge-to-kubernetes?view=vs-2019) and [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/configure-bridge-to-kubernetes?view=vs-2019) you can read in Microsoft's official docs.

You may also take a look at [Use Bridge to Kubernetes with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/bridge-to-kubernetes).